# c++ how to write/read ofstream in unicode / utf8

Tags: c++, string, unicode, utf-8, character-encoding

I have UTF-8 text file , that I'm reading using simple :

```
ifstream in("test.txt");
```

Now I'd like to create a new file that will be UTF-8 encoding or Unicode. 
How can I do this with `ofstream` or other? 
This creates ansi Encoding.

```
ofstream out(fileName.c_str(), ios::out | ios::app | ios::binary);
```

Comment: This article might help: [UTF-8 With C++ in a Portable Way](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/string/utf8cpp.aspx)

Comment: What do you mean utf8 isn't Unicode?

Comment: Please include a minimal but complete code sample exhibiting the behavior you decribe.

Comment: @Jörgen - Unicode can be encoded in many formats, of which UTF-8 is only one. UTF-16 encoded Unicode is just as much Unicode as is UTF-8 encoded Unicode, for example, but trying to parse it as UTF-8 is most likely to make your decoder crash and burn. So, better to be clear about which encoding of the Unicode character table one is talking about.

Comment: Utf8 *is* as much Unicode as utf16 and utf32. There are no character tables. Unicode is a mapping of codes to characters. UtfX are ways of representing the codes in a portable way.

Answer (score 5):

Ok, about the portable variant. It is easy, if you use the `C++11` standard (because there are a lot of additional includes like `"utf8"`, which solves this problem forever).

But if you want to use multi-platform code with older standards, you can use this method to write with streams:

1. [Read the article about UTF converter for streams](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38242/Reading-UTF-8-with-C-streams)
2. Add `stxutif.h` to your project from sources above
3. Open the file in ANSI mode and add the BOM to the start of a file, like this:

   ```
   std::ofstream fs;
   fs.open(filepath, std::ios::out|std::ios::binary);

   unsigned char smarker[3];
   smarker[0] = 0xEF;
   smarker[1] = 0xBB;
   smarker[2] = 0xBF;

   fs << smarker;
   fs.close();
   ```
4. Then open the file as `UTF` and write your content there:

   ```
   std::wofstream fs;
   fs.open(filepath, std::ios::out|std::ios::app);

   std::locale utf8_locale(std::locale(), new utf8cvt<false>);
   fs.imbue(utf8_locale); 

   fs << .. // Write anything you want...
   ```

Comment: "The UCS-2 and UTF-16 encodings specify the Unicode Byte Order Mark (BOM) for use at the beginnings of text files, which may be used for byte ordering detection (or byte endianness detection). "    - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark

Comment: Don't write a BOM for UTF-8! "The Unicode Standard neither requires nor recommends the use of the BOM for UTF-8, " http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark

Comment: Good article to update this theme 'New Options for Managing Character Sets in the Microsoft C/C++ Compiler' https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2016/02/22/new-options-for-managing-character-sets-in-the-microsoft-cc-compiler/