# File content truncated when using polish characters

Tags: c++, file, character, ofstream, polish

Code:

```
#include <fstream>

const wchar_t * testArray[] =
{
    L"Wszystkie kategorie równoważne",
    L"Oczekiwane przepływy pieniężne",
    L"Risk i dojrzałość",
    L"Pozycja strategiczna i lata na rynku",
    L"Prawdopodobieństwo oszacowania"
};

void FaultyFunction(void)
{
    std::wofstream file("test.txt");
    for (int i = 0 ; i < 100 ; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0 ; j < 5 ; ++j)
        {
            file << testArray[j] << L'\t';
        }
        file << L'\n';
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    FaultyFunction();
    return 0;
}
```

"test.txt" after execution:

> Wszystkie kategorie równowa

(Yes, that's the whole file!)

Now, I don't know if that's a problem with `std::wofstream`, file encoding or what but the result is at the very least strange. But when I remove polish letters:

```
const wchar_t * testArray[] =
{
    L"Wszystkie kategorie rownowazne",
    L"Oczekiwane przeplywy pieniezne",
    L"Risk i dojrzalosc",
    L"Pozycja strategiczna i lata na rynku",
    L"Prawdopodobienstwo oszacowania"
};
```

The file content is as expected:

> Wszystkie kategorie rownowazne    Oczekiwane przeplywy pieniezne  Risk i dojrzalosc   Pozycja strategiczna i lata na rynku    Prawdopodobienstwo oszacowania
>   Wszystkie kategorie rownowazne    Oczekiwane przeplywy pieniezne  Risk i dojrzalosc   Pozycja strategiczna i lata na rynku    Prawdopodobienstwo oszacowania
>   Wszystkie kategorie rownowazne    Oczekiwane przeplywy pieniezne  Risk i dojrzalosc   Pozycja strategiczna i lata na rynku    Prawdopodobienstwo oszacowania
>   ... (it goes on like this for the remaining 97 lines)

And to add insult to injury when I use the very same `testArray` (**with** polish chars) to write some things in an *.xls file (using libxl library) everything works just fine.

What's wrong? How can I save polish letters in a text file?

**Edit:**
Actually, when I tried the same code but with `std::string` and `std::ofstream` (not wide), it also worked fine (**with** polish letters). So what's the problem with the wide chars?

Comment: probably relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5026555/c-how-to-write-read-ofstream-in-unicode-utf8

Comment: What is the file size of the one-line file that's produced?

Comment: @DrewDormann 27 bytes

Answer (score 1):

[Discussed on StackOverflow, MSDN, CodeGuru, CodeProject etc.](https://www.google.cz/search?q=c%2B%2B%20wofstream%20unicode) dozens of times already. However, next code for a C++ console application prepared in Visual Studio 2013 could help:

```
#include "stdafx.h"     // added by Visual Studio
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <codecvt>
#include <locale>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <io.h>

const std::locale utf8_locale = std::locale(std::locale(),
    new std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>());      // prepare parameter for imbue call
const wchar_t* testArray[] =
{
    L"Wszystkie kategorie równoważne",
    L"Oczekiwane przepływy pieniężne",
    L"Risk i dojrzałość",
    L"Pozycja strategiczna i lata na rynku",
    L"Prawdopodobieństwo oszacowania"
};

void FaultyFunction(void)
{
    _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT); // for debugging; if omitted then
                                           // std::wcout would be truncated as well
    std::wofstream test_file("test.txt");
    // test_file << L"\xEF\xBB\xBF";     // Byte Order Mark: not required nor recommended
                                         //       important: write BOM before imbue
    test_file.imbue(utf8_locale);        // set the locale of the stream (and buffer
                                         //       if any) to the specified locale
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; ++j)
        {
            test_file << testArray[j] << L'\t';
            // std::wcout << testArray[j] << L'\n';  // for debugging
        }
        test_file << L'\n';
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    FaultyFunction();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I got it to work in one project, but in another, i get `assertion failure` at `_setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);`