# Where's the table of values for printing special symbols in C++?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, character-encoding, escaping

To get certain special characters in C++ we can enclose an escape sequence of octal values within single quotes thus `'\nnn'` where `nnn` is an octal code.
The *only* example I currently know of is `'\370'` for the degree symbol (°).
Where is a list of other such values for printing non-simple-ascii characters in C++?

In a code table at [ascii-code.com](http://www.ascii-code.com/) are these two entries

```
DEC OCT HEX BIN Symbol  HTML Number HTML Name   Description
176 260 B0  10110000    °    &#176; &deg;       Degree sign
248 370 F8  11111000    ø    &#248; &oslash;    Latin small letter o with slash
```

which are clearly *not* correct for my problem – i.e., assigning `'\nnn'` to a `char` variable or inserting to an outputstream via `cout <<` in Visual Studio 2015.
Where is a correct table? It has something to do with "codesets" but I don't know what codeset is the default in VS 2015 or how to change the codeset.

It was suggested below that I "use `\u####` where `####` is a number representing the Unicode value of the wanted character. For example `\u2014` will print an — (em-dash)." However, when I try that example – or any others from [rapidtables.com/code/text/unicode-characters](http://www.rapidtables.com/code/text/unicode-characters.htm) or [wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters)  – I don't get the character expected for the given code. For example, `\20AC` should produce a Euro sign (€) but I get a big C with cedilla (Ç). Where is the table of Unicode values for printing special characters in C++ in Visual Studio 2015?

Comment: Define "my problem". The table on ascii-code.com gives the characters in the `ISO-8859-1` codeset. What codeset are you using?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik - See extra info.

Comment: I recommend you to use `\u####` where `####` is a number representing the Unicode value of the wanted character. For example `\u2014` will print an **—** (em-dash).

Comment: @sergiol - See extra info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: how to change the codeset]

Next code for a C++ console application prepared in Visual Studio 2013 could help. [Based on this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36813461/3439404).

```
// 37645602.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"     // added by Visual Studio
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <codecvt>
#include <locale>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <io.h>

const wchar_t* testArray[] =
{
    L"€ ° ø — ď π щ",                                      // for debugging
    L"\u20AC \u00b0 \u00F8 \u2014 \u010f \u03c0 \u0449"    // the same characters
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);

    for (int j = 0; j < 2; ++j)
    {
        std::wcout << testArray[j] << L'\n';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Output**:

```
==> 37645602.exe
€ ° ø — ď π щ
€ ° ø — ď π щ
```

Tested using a mix of Latin, Slavic, Cyrillic and Greek characters (output from a script similar to this [Alt KeyCode Finder](https://superuser.com/a/1047961/376602)):

```
==> altcodes "€°ø—ďπщ"
Ch Unicode    Alt?      mod 256     UTF-8   IME 0405/cs-CZ; CP852; ANSI 1250
 €  U+20AC    8364        …172…  0xE282AC   Euro Sign
 °  U+00B0     176        …176…    0xC2B0   Degree Sign
 ø  U+00F8     248        …248…    0xC3B8   Latin Small Letter O With Stroke
 —  U+2014    8212         …20…  0xE28094   Em Dash
 ď  U+010F     271         …15…    0xC48F   Latin Small Letter D With Caron
 π  U+03C0     960        …192…    0xCF80   Greek Small Letter Pi
 щ  U+0449    1097         …73…    0xD189   Cyrillic Small Letter Shcha
 €°ø—ďπщ
```