# How to write in a xml file without starting with question mark c++

Tags: c++

I need to print on the 1st row:

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

code:

```
ofstream outfile("test_xml.xml");
outfile << "﻿<?xml version = \"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>" << endl; 
outfile.close();
```

and I get:

```
?<?xml version = "1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

with the question mark at the start of the row

I also tried to write:

```
ofstream outfile("test_xml.xml");
outfile << "﻿cat" << endl; 
outfile.close();
```

and I get:

```
?cat
```

with the question mark at the start of the row

where is the problem?

Comment: Are you sure the leading '?' is really a question mark and not some text editor's representation of a non-printable character?   Look at it in a hex editor and make sure it is actually a question mark

Comment: Could indicate that the file is UTF-8 or so. I had this too but I can't recall what it was in the end. Some kind of magic (number) ;-)

Comment: @MartinB. An UTF-8 BOM is apparently 3 bytes, so that's not it.

Comment: @Quentin Unless the other two bytes aren't being printed by whatever is viewing the files.

Comment: in HEX editor I get : 3f 3c 3f 78  ... so it's the same as the second one : ?<?x

Comment: Could you provide a minimal verifiable example so that we can test on our machines? http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve , read for more info

Comment: If you are doing anything more complex than this, it is better to use an XML library. And surely you will be doing something more complex, right? For example, you are writing an assertion that the file (stream) is encoded using UTF-8. That's great communication but is it true? A library would make sure the actual encoding is written.

Answer (score 1):

Was able to reproduce this problem on VS Community 2015.  It seems that the compiler and IDE environment are aware of the intent to encode this string as something other than ASCII text.

On this line:

```
    outfile << "﻿<?xml version = \"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>" << endl;
```

I received the warning:

> `warning C4566: character represented by universal-character-name '\uFEFF' cannot be represented in the current code page (1252)`

After some searching, found a number of related articles.  Ultimately, the simplest example solution came from here: [`std::codecvt`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/codecvt)

## Technique 1:

*Very simple; solves your specific problem; does not provide UTF-8 BOM.*

Try this simple adaptation of your code (adhering to popular convention that the namespace should be called out explicitly wherever applicable):

```
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
    std::ofstream outfile("test_xml.xml");
    outfile << u8"﻿<?xml version = \"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>" << std::endl;
    outfile.close();

    return 0;
}
```

*Reading* the file has its own complications, covered in the same link noted above.

## Technique 2:

*More complex; provides UTF-8 BOM.*

Refer to this SO question: [c++ how to write/read ofstream in unicode / utf8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5026555/c-how-to-write-read-ofstream-in-unicode-utf8)